# Click to buttons in Menu item in ExtJs4.1

Tags: extjs4

Why I have this error every time when press button in menu ( Extjs4.1). It happens when I trying to click at any button in Menu below.

**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getPageBox'**

Here is code:

```
dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    items: [{
        text: _('Add'),
        iconCls: 'entry_add',
        action: 'add',
    },{
        text: _('Search')+':',
    },{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        hideLabel: true,
        width: 160,
        name: 'searchfield',
        enableKeyEvents: true,
    },{
        xtype: 'tbfill',
    },{
        text: _('Delete'),
        iconCls: 'entry_delete',
        action: 'delete',
    },{
        text: _('Refresh'),
        iconCls: 'entry_refresh',
        action: 'refresh',
    },{
        iconCls: 'entry_refresh',
        text: 'Actions',
        menu: {
            xtype: 'menu',
            floating: true,
            items: [{
                text: _('Create Order'),
                iconCls: 'entry_delete',
                action: 'createorder',
            },{
                text: _('Stocktalking'),
                iconCls: 'entry_delete',
                action: 'stocktalking',
            },{
                text: _('Export'),
                iconCls: 'entry_refresh',
                action: 'export',
            },{
                text: _('Import'),
                iconCls: 'entry_refresh',
                action: 'import',
            }],
        },
    }]
```

Comment: In Ext4.0.7 works properly seems like a bug

Comment: I've tested it in 4.1.0-RC3 without errors. Do you have any other codes that you may think it's about them?

Comment: MMMM, not works also on 4.1RC3, will search for other errors.